# How to train data of different lengths in machine learning?

Tags: data-science, training-data

I am analyzing the text of some literary works and I want to look at the distance between certain words in the text. Specifically, I am looking for parallelism.

Since I can’t know the specific number of tokens in a text I can’t simply put all words in the text in the training data because it would not be uniform across all training data.

For example, the text:

“I have a dream that my four little children will one day live in a nation where they will not be judged by the color of their skin but by the content of their character. I have a dream today."

Is not the same text length as

"My fellow Americans, ask not what your country can do for you, ask what you can do for your country."

So therefore I could not columns out of each word and then assign the distance in a row because the lengths would be different.

How could I go about representing this in training data?  I was under the assumption that training data had to be the same type and length.

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem you can use something called pad_sequence,so follow this process, sure you are going to transform the data throught some word embedding techniques like TF-IDF or any other algorithm, and after finishing the process of converting the textual data into vectors and by using the shape method you can figure the maximum length you have and than use that maximum in the pad-sequence method, and here is a how you implement this method:

```
'''
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
padded_data= pad_sequences(name-of-your-data, maxlen=your-maximum-shape, padding='post', truncating='post')
'''
```